# Composition surjection, bijection

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could you tell me if I'm right, assuming that if:

$X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{g} Y'$, where $f$ is an isometry (bijection)

and

$X \xrightarrow{f '} Y'$ is also an isometry,

then $g$ must be surjective?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful : an isometry is injective but needs not be surjective. Consider the isometry $f : x \mapsto (x,0)$ : it is an isometry from the real line into the plane, but is not surjective. Thus if you take $g$ to be the identity, with $X = \mathbb{R}$, $Y=Y'=\mathbb{R}^2$, you have a counterexample.

If however you assume that both $f$ and $g$ are bijections, then their composition will still be bijective and in particular surjective. Also, if $X=Y'$ are finite dimensional affine spaces, your claim will also be true for dimension reasons.